# Getting the map value with Golang

Tags: dictionary, go

I couldn't do it because I didn't fully understand the logic, but you can look at my code example and output below. I just want to return the country name as a variable in the output.

Json File : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coderantidote/0894cf7c5204d4c712207ff9162d044d/raw/ab9ec19dcfecd93addb4b1961a2506b34164c090/tld

```js
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
    
        tld "github.com/jpillora/go-tld"
        gojsonq "github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq/v2"
    )
    
    func main() {
        
        urls := []string{
            "http://google.com",
            "https://eduuk.co.uk/",
            "https://www.medi-cal.ca.gov/",
        }
    
        for _, url := range urls {
            u, _ := tld.Parse(url)
            jq := gojsonq.New().File("./tld.json").From("tlds")
            tldSlice := strings.Split(u.TLD, ".")
            if len(tldSlice) == 2 {
                jq.Where("fields.tld", "=", tldSlice[1]).Select("fields.country")
            } else {
                jq.Where("fields.tld", "strictContains", tldSlice[0]).Select("fields.country")
            }
    
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", u.TLD)
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", jq.Get())
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
com
[map[country:Commercial organizations]]
co.uk
[map[country:United Kingdom]]
gov
[map[country:US government]]
```

Comment: could you please share the sample object/content of `./tld.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```golang
fmt.Printf("%s\n", u.TLD)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", jq.First().(map[string]interface{})["country"])
```